# how to redirect all page request to one page without url change

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect all pages on my site (including index) to `UnderWork.html`
and I'm doing this using `.htaccess` with this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ UnderWork.html
```

...and its works fine.
Now I am adding some more code to my `.htaccess` to redirect all traffic to the non-www domain and now my code looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.in
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.in$1 [R=permanent,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ UnderWork.html
```

Here is where I have a problem. If I enter a URL like: `domain.in/xyz` then it works as before, but if I use a URL like: `www.domain.in/xyz` then Apache converts it to `coincart.inxyz/`.

What am I doing wrong here? How can I get what i want? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below are rules that work for me:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Adding trailing slash for directory requests.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/www$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ http://example.com/$1/ [R=permanent]

# External redirection from www subdomain to non-www domain.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://example.com/$1 [L,R=permanent]

# Internal redirection to index.php for nonexistent URLs.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$
RewriteRule . /index.php [L,QSA]
```

To show a custom page when a directory root (domain root in particular) is requested, use the Apache's `DirectoryIndex` directive:

```
DirectoryIndex UnderWork.html
```

Comment: Thanx. I'm going to try this.

Comment: Thanx. This works fine. But if i remove my index.html from my server then UnderWork.html appear with response code (403 forbidden) can you explain that ? And you have any fix  for that ?

Comment: @Rakesh I've updated the answer with info on how to specify a custom directory-index handler page.

Comment: Gr8  idea :) you save my time .. Thank you so much